# How to knit a simple statistics table from RMarkdown to .docx?

Tags: r, r-markdown, docx

I am working on a manuscript in RMarkdown. The journal I want to submit in requires simple word tables in the submitted manuscript (see example below).

Example table:

[image]

Let's assume I have a data frame, which contains water quality data. I want to do a summary statistics of this data frame, using, let's say "summary" function or something similar and then show it as a table in my document.

I have read some topics like https://community.rstudio.com/t/nice-tables-when-knitting-to-word/3840/5 but the examples there are too complex for my needs. I just want to have a simple table, which contains statistics information.

Knitting to Word is important part for me, because my collaborators don't use Rmd, so I need to keep it in *.docx for further comments etc.

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: This isn't the sort of question that SO likes:  you're asking for opinions and suggestions, rather than a specific technical question.  There are a lot of R packages and functions that produce tables, with different emphases:  I'd suggest you should just use a very simple one, e.g. `knitr::kable()`, possibly with `kableExtra` to modify it.  Other possibilities if that's not enough are `tables`, `gt`, `flextable`, `rtables`, etc.  You should say specifically what you need to do if you can't find it yourself.